# How to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning warning when uppercasing string values in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change all values in a column of my pandas df to uppercase. The values are strings containing both letters and numbers.

I used the code below:

```
df['Cd'] = df['Cd'].str.upper()
```

The job was performed, however, I got the warning below:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I then tried the code below:

```
df['Cd'] = df['Cd'].apply(lambda x: str(x).upper())
```

I still ran to the same warning.

Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: What pandas version are you using?

Comment: I don't thiink that should appear for older versions anyway right? Just for indexing on a column

Comment: This happens all the time, when you `df` is a slice of another (bigger) data.

Comment: I just tested this and it gives me no warnings for pandas 0.25

Comment: I don't recall getting it for just indexing on a column though, no slicing done here, but not sure on older versions

Comment: `df` is not the original data frame in the first place. You probably got it from another data frame, hence is a copy and whenever you modify it it'll raise that warning

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with uppercasing string values and everything to do with the fact that you're setting it on a dataframe which is itself a slice/copy of another dataframe. The title was misleading.